# Footnote to figure

Tags: floats, captions, footnotes

I want to add a source address of my address like this:

[image: Current status]

But the address must start from the beginning of figure like this:
[image: Target]

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: You need to be a little more forthcoming in terms of how you currently display your `Source: ...` content. Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current behaviour? The solution might be as simple as using `\raggedright \textbf{Source:} ...` with appropriate paragraphs (empty lines or `\par`) in your `figure` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the code from your previous question, I add a command for stating the source to be typeset along with the image in a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

\captionsetup{
  format=hang,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  figureposition=top,
}


\newcommand{\includegraphicswithsource}[3][]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}\\
  Source: \url{#3}
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionbox{some text goes here. This text is just 
  some dummy replacement for the figure caption}{%
   \includegraphicswithsource[width=6cm]{example-image-a}{www.dummy.com}%
}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One option is to put the image and its source text inside a `varwidth` (requires the [`varwidth`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) package) environment:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand\Source[1]{\par\textbf{Source:} \url{#1}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{some text goes here. This text is just some dummy replacement for the figure caption}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}
\Source{www.dummy.com}
\end{varwidth}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you know the figure width, a simple minipage will do the job:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand\Source[1]{\par\textbf{Source:} \url{#1}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{some text goes here. This text is just some dummy replacement for the figure caption}
\begin{minipage}{6cm}% the width here is equal to the image width
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}
\Source{www.dummy.com}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possibility using a `\stackunder`.  I show two figures, the second with the `boxhandler` package to give the OP a similar caption format to what was presented, although it is below, rather than above the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,lipsum,boxhandler}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Lorem imsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
  Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.  Aenean massa.}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\stackunder{\includegraphics[width=3in]{demo}}{\textbf{Source:} www.dummy.com}
\end{figure}

\bxfigure[ht]
{Lorem imsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
  Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.  Aenean massa.}
{\def\stackalignment{l}
\stackunder{\includegraphics[width=3in]{demo}}{\textbf{Source:} www.dummy.com}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I try to compile your code, MikTeX gives error: `program can't start because Qt5WinExtras.dll is missing`. All other my LaTeX files I can normally compile. Do your code require something extra for compilation?

Comment: I just discover that source of my problem is package `boxhandler`. If I omit it and second example in your answer, then all works as expected. Nice solution!

Comment: @Zarko  It does not require anything extra, to my knowledge.  I do not even recognize the error message as being related to LaTeX.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for the clarification.  I wrote `boxhandler` but have no Idea what could be happening to bring on the error.  But I'll look around.

Comment: After recent MikTeX update all works! Recently it has some problems with .dll libraries etc. It seems that now all is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I used the `measuredfigure` environment, from `threeparttable`, to have a caption of the width of the figure, and the `copyrightbox`, which is done to add such an information to tables/figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, threeparttable}
\usepackage{copyrightbox, url}
\urlstyle{sf}
\captionsetup{format=hang}

\begin{document}

\begin{measuredfigure}
  \centering
  \caption{some text goes here. This text is just some dummy replacement for the figure caption}
  \copyrightbox[b]{
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{sourceimg}}
  {Source: \url{www.dummy.com}}
\end{measuredfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]