# MiKTeX 2.9 missing dll?

Tags: errors, miktex, updating

Since yesterday's (22.6.2015) update, my MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 8.1 64-bit repeatedly crashes with an error message that is something like: `missing Qt5WinExtras.dll`.

This file is not present either in the MiKTeX binaries folder or in my system.

Comment: Run the package manager (admin if you have a multiuser installation), update the package list (menu repositories->synchronize), then check for new packages starting with `miktex-`.

Comment: I have the same problem, which after today updating of MikTeX and synchronizing package package list (updating after this says, that there is no new packages), still persist.

Comment: @Zarko: Running the update manager doesn't help. It doesn't show new packages. You must look at the package list in the package manager (admin).

Comment: @UlrikeFisher, I'm lost in this. I run synchronization in package manager, check, if all MikTeX 64-bit executable are present. Between them are miktex-qt5-bin-x64, but I still get error -- not at all files, just for some of them, for example at @StevenBSeglets answer on `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251596/footnote-to-figure`.

Comment: I really wished you all would put a bit more effort in bug reports. Why didn't you mention directly that it is texworks that reports the crash and that one has to use  and a special document to trigger it? Make a bug report in the miktex bug tracker.

Comment: The error is related to the on-the-fly installation and the "Ask me first option".

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the on-the-fly installation of missing packages. When the "ask me first" is used miktex tries to show a dialog and fails. This explains the erratic number of documents showing the problem.

I made a bug report. In the meantime one can avoid the crash by setting the option to "yes" or "no", and by installing missing package before the compilation.